# ShowSeriesName attaching Y value label

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am writing a loop to create and format an XY scatter chart in Excel 2010.  In my loop I added .ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True and the series name shows up in my chart but the Y value label is added as well.  To remove the Y value label I added .ApplyDataLabels ShowValue:=False to my code but that turns off the series name label as well.  Here is my code:

```
If (Range("Q" & m) >= 40 And Range("R" & m) >= 40) Then
.ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True
.ApplyDataLabels ShowValue:=False 'set to false because it didn't work
End If
```

Basically I only need the series name to show up in my chart, not the series name and Y value label.  Has anybody else had this problem or know a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set both parameters in one line, like:

```
If (Range("Q" & m) >= 40 And Range("R" & m) >= 40) Then
   .ApplyDataLabels ShowSeriesName:=True, ShowValue:=False
End If
```

And give us information if anything changed. If not, please add `With...` line to your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply.  Adding ShowValue:=False to the same line as ShowSeriesName solved my issue.  You're the best!